# Enum as key of HashTable

Tags: java, collections, hashtable

I'm writting a Schedule structure in Java.
I have a Hashtable with enum Day as Key and list of timeranges as value.
Like this :

```
public enum Day {
    SUNDAY, MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY,
    THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY 
}

private Hashtable<Day,TimeRanges> _applyCalendar;
```

where TimeRanges class is ...

```
public class TimeRanges implements List<TimeRange> {
```

When I add elements to _appleCalendar I do this :

```
public void addApplyDay(Day day,TimeRanges trs) {
    if (! _applyCalendar.contains(day)) {
        _applyCalendar.put(day, trs);
    } else {
        for ( TimeRange t : trs) {
            _applyCalendar.get(day).add(t);
        }
    }

}
```

My problem is method contains() doesn't work right.
HashTable can't be able to found existing element in hashtable,all time enter in the first condition :S

Is there any way to do this without should to declare Day as class and implement comareTo() ??

Comment: Why are you using `Hashtable` at all?

Comment: With Enum keys you also have the option of using the (often overlooked) [EnumMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html), it's backed by an array and all operations are constant time.  Not that it would make a difference here, but doesn't cost anything, either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want to use `.containsKey()` instead of `contains()`. `contains()` will search the actual objects whereas `containsKey()` will search the keys.

```
public void addApplyDay(Day day,TimeRanges trs) {
    if (! _applyCalendar.containsKey(day)) { // << use containsKey
        _applyCalendar.put(day, trs);
    } else {
        for ( TimeRange t : trs) {
            _applyCalendar.get(day).add(t);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Great illustration of why never to use the ancient `Hashtable` class!